# Chessboard Class give me error

Tags: c++

This is a class for a Chessboard .
How can i resolve the error that the compiler give ? Thanks

**The error is " expected unqualified-id before '[' token|"**

```
#ifndef SCACCHIERA_H_INCLUDED
#define SCACCHIERA_H_INCLUDED

class Chess {
public:


private:
    unsigned int rows = 0;
    unsigned int columns = 0;
    int[][]mat = new int[rows][columns];
};


#endif // SCACCHIERA_H_INCLUDED
```

With the help of a user i changed the code to

```
class Chess {

public:
    Chess(unsigned int a):mat(mat[a][a]){};

private:
    int mat[0][0];
};
```

But now the compiler gives me the error
***incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [0][0]'|***

Comment: You might want to include what errors you're getting rather than making people try and guess.

Comment: This is not Java.  You need to review the syntax for declaring array variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[][]mat = new int[rows][columns];
```

should be

```
int mat[rows][columns];
```

if `rows` and `columns` are constants.
Or

```
class Chess {
public:
    Chess(int r, int c) {
        rows = r;
        columns = c;
        mat = new int*[rows];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            mat[i] = new int[columns];
    }

private:
    unsigned int rows = 0;
    unsigned int columns = 0;
    int** mat = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: I did not think could be so complicated

Comment: [Your code](http://ideone.com/VPqLqV) doesn't even work with constants and the right pointer type specified: http://ideone.com/alQWy1 Provide a working live demo (ideone, coliru, etc.) please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here.

> int[][]mat = new int[rows][columns];

First make it public. If you need it to be private make sure you provide functions to access this private array.
You could simply declare it as

```
int mat[row][column];
```

If you want to understand what you are doing clearly, it looks something like this. You are declaring a 2 dimensional array. The above simple line is handled somewhat like this inside the compiler. The declaration would be:

```
int **mat = new *[columns];
for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
ary[columns] = new int[row];
```

This will create a 2D array of columns * row. i.e if there are 2 columns and 5 rows. you will get something like this:

[+] -> [*****]
[+] -> [*****]

Where + is the column and holds the address to row arrays.